# How to turn off talkback feature on Galaxy S2 ICS 4.03

Tags: settings, accessibility, talk-back

I have turned on Talkback to see if it worked on My Galaxy S2.That also disabled my touch screen scrolling .Now I cannot turn off talkback because I cannot scroll through the setting menu. What should I do?

Comment: If you have a USB OTG Adapter you can just plug in a regular keyboard and use the arrow keys to navigate.

Answer (score 1):

In this [post](http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-galaxy-nexus/194024-talkback-mode.html), it says to: double tap and scroll with two fingers.
Let us know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use 2 fingers to scroll through menu.